# Как на python можно авторизироваться на сайте в всплывающем окне

Tags: python, парсер, requests

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно авторизироваться на сайте с помощью requests на python, где пароль и логин вводятся в таком всплывающем окне? Везде пишут про обычное модальное окно а тут оно прям поверх браузера.
[image: Пример окна]

Кода на странице ни какого нет(
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Данное окно - стандартное окно браузера для запроса учетных данных при базовой авторизации. Вам нужно просто передать логин/пароль в качестве аргумента вызова

```py
 requests.get('url', auth=('username', 'password'))
```

Comment: спасибо! Помогло

Answer (score 0):

Очень долго гуглил, в итоге в моём случае из Python получилось только вот таким способом авторизоваться в таком-же окошке:

```
res = requests.get('http://{host}/cgi-bin/get_system_info.cgi', auth=HTTPDigestAuth('root', 'root'))
```

Ещё получилось авторизоваться передав логин пароль в строку браузера так:

```
http://root:root@host
```

Что подсмотрел здесь https://forum.ixbt.com/topic.cgi?id=24:025716
Но через Requests этот способ не сработал.

Ещё некоторая инфа кажется в тему http://www.opennet.ru/base/dev/cgi_auth_401.txt.html